# Refused to load the script : Content-Security-Policy

Tags: javascript, axios, content-security-policy, script-src

Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

```
**script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js')**
```

so i tried adding this meta header though it throws the same error

```
meta(http-equiv='Content-Security-Policy' content="script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'")
```

Comment: why are you using such an ancient version?

Comment: Use the integrity and other headers `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-3BBFWr73Xrf8GRjO+0pl0cbVwESBvg3ovnuCXpoqOkC/mkt/hTkFtutUPrwRz8eLySYvy5v1daulkyUZYvH8jw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>`

Comment: I was checking whether it was problem with newer so I went with older version of script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using helmet in node then this worked for me

`app.use( helmet({ contentSecurityPolicy: false }) );`

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a default Content Security Policy served as a response header. Adding another policy in meta tag can only make it stricter as all content needs to pass all policies. You need to identify what sets the CSP with "script-src 'self'" and modify that policy.

Comment: Yes thank you it worked i was using node helmet, by setting CSP: to false it loads scripts